# Woocommerce Shipping based on condition and cart value

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to set shipping rule in woocommerce. My conditions are as follows.

1. $25 for selected postal codes; if total cart value is < $250
2. $0 / Free for same selected postal codes; if total cart value is >= $250
3. Flat $25 for another set of postal codes (let's say Zone B)
4. Generic message to call; if shipping/billing address is international.

I tried using the Shipping Zone, I created zones and when I apply "Flat Rate", I'm not sure how should I put the condition into it. there is no guideline from woocommerce which explains in details of using [qty] [cost] [fee]

I did this: ([cost]<250)+25 (obviously, it's not working.)
again, I did add second rule: ([cost]>=250)+0 (again this is same)

both are showing up if the postal code matches in shipping/billing address, but not is satisfying the condition.

my question is that is there a way to make this conditional based shipping rule work? either by coding or by manipulating it from the backend?

Or do I need to purchase the premium plugin for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible through backend, but you'll have to use 2 shipping methods.

Flat rate with your shipping cost and free shipping with minimum order amount.

Adjust according to your zones.

Zone A:

http://puu.sh/tJDpg/be34c5739d.png

http://puu.sh/tJDsJ/7aae204650.png

And zone B will be just flat rate

Edit:

To hide other shipping methods when free shipping is available:

You'll need to hook into `woocommerce_package_rates`.

Use one of the snippets in WooComm docs based on your version.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/

Comment: I'm already using 2 shipping method from backend, the problem I'm getting is into conditions. If you are sure that it can be achieved from backend, then can you please provide example or steps how it should be done?

Comment: See the edit, I've included screenshots.

Comment: Hi @Aniruddha, I'm sorry It's been a while on this thread. I did created the shipping method as you suggested, but still it's not satisfying the conditional logic.

On the frontend, it's showing both Free shipping method and cost for specific zone.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Is free shipping showing up even if min cost is not satisfied?

Comment: let's say, I created a zone A, which have 2 following shipping rule

1. 25 If the cart value is less than 250
2. Free if the cart value is greater than 250.

I created both flat rate and free shipping rule for the same Zone A, now If 

1. cart value is less than 250, it's showing 25 as shipping cost
2. cart value is greater than 250, it's showing both option a. 25 and b. free shipping. whereas it should only show, free shipping.

I hope I mentioned it correctly, If you still confusion then let me know.

Comment: Check the edit, and let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks Man, hooking into `woocommerce_package_rates` worked.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not available in default woocommerce.
So You Can Use this Plugin for set shipping rule in woocommerce.

first review this plugin
Table Rate Shipping : https://woocommerce.com/products/table-rate-shipping/ And then buy it.

I hope it useful it.

Comment: Hi @jignesh, just for a small logic, is it really worth of buying this $99 plugin,  all other requirement is been done, it's just that conditional logic needs to be satisfied.